# JMS template credentials default value

Tags: java, spring, jboss, jms, message-queue

Hello everyone I'm trying to work with jboss messaging, does anyone knows the default value for these `java.naming.security.principal` and `java.naming.security.credentials` or how can I set them?

```
 <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
      <property name="environment">
       <props>
        <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">jnp://localhost:8080</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.factory.url.pkgs">org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.security.principal">value</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.security.credentials">value</prop>
       </props>
      </property>
     </bean>
```

I'm trying to instansiate the `<bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">` I'm guessing that this is the cause why jboss timeouts when starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its probably `admin/admin` or `guest/guest`